# Light Strength option missing

Tags: interface, light

I'm just a beginner in Blender and trying to learn. I am following a tutorial and have a problem. I'm missing the light 'Strength' option.
I couldn't find the answer to what could be the issue. I would appreciate it if someone would let me know what I can do to have the 'Strength' option.

[image]

Comment: Your question is incomplete.  Can you please provide the version of Blender you are using and perhaps a link to the tutorial?  Have you chosen the correct rendering engine?  Your screenshot shows you are using Eevee.  Could the tutorial be using a different engine, such as Cycles?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I was using version 2.8 and Eevee render engine. I got a comment that helped me, which was installing the newest version, which is 2.81 and the 'strength' option appeared. The tutorial I was following was using version 2.8 for demonstration so I didn't expect that my issue was, in the end, with version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest Blender, because i have it; or try to unistall and install again
[image]

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you! This indeed helped me! I installed version 2.81 and the "strength" option appeared : ) I was actually surprised because in the tutorial I was following, the guy was using version 2.8. But in the end, installing a newer version helped, thanks!